# Recommendations for a usable, fast GPL-compatible derivative-free numerical optimization library that can be interfaced to C++

Tags: optimization, reference-request, libraries, c++

I am dealing with optimization of functions for which I do not have derivatives available, and the optimization is not constrained.  I am searching for a high quality GNU Public License-compatible optimization library compatible with the C++ language. So far I have managed to find [OPT++](http://acts.nersc.gov/opt++/).

Can someone recommend this or some other library?

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to C++ and GPL?  Does the library merely need to be compatible with C++ and GPL licensing?  I can't think of a good reason for restricting yourself in this search.

Comment: @Aron Ahmadia: I need to couple it with OpenFOAM, which is GPL based and written in C++. An alternative would be a library written in another language that has a C++ wrapper layer.

Comment: Okay, please update your question since you are looking for a library that is GPL-compatible and easy to interface with C++ (this is almost always done through C bindings, which C++, unsurprisingly, provides).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[OPT++](https://software.sandia.gov/opt++/) is used internally by [Dakota](http://dakota.sandia.gov/index.html) (Sandia), which is much more than an optimization library and is released under the LGPL. You should also take a look at [TAO](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/tao/) (ANL), released under a BSD-like license. An introduction to both OPT++ and TAO can be found [here](http://acts.nersc.gov/events/SIAMCSE05/docs/OPT++TAO.pdf). Other alternatives are [MOOCHO](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/moocho/), [NOMAD](http://www.gerad.ca/NOMAD/Project/Home.html), and [HOPSPACK](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/hopspack/), which are, as far as I know, also LGPL licensed.

Both Sandia and ANL offer automatic differentiation packages, like [Sacado](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/docs/r10.12/packages/sacado/doc/html/index.html) and [ADIFOR](http://web.anl.gov/techtransfer/Software_Shop/ADIFOR/adifor.html)/[ADIC](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/adic/), that should play well with their general purpose numerical libraries [Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/)/[PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/).

Answer (score 5):

The library [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) meets your requirements.  I have used it in the past and I am satisfied with its interface and results.

Comment: Is there similar library with the ability to run in parallel?

Comment: I don't know of any such library.  With NLopt it is possible to parallelize the evaluation of constraints (see http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Reference#Vector-valued_constraints ) but I don't know if there are any plans for implementing parallelism at the objective function evaluation level.